# Ansible facts in Dictionary for Jinja Template

Tags: ansible

I am trying to template out building servers and cannot get the jinja syntax correct.  I have a var dictionary (assume "ansible_hostname" is "server" gathered from facts):

```
server:
  ip: 111.111.111.111
```

I am trying to call the variable in my template:

```
"{{ hostvars['ansible_hostname'].['ip'] }}"
```

I just cannot seem to figure out what is needed.  A poke in the right direction would be great.

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*inventory_hostname*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) and remove the dot when brackets *`[]`* are used.

```yaml
    "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ip'] }}"
```

For example, this inventory and playbook

```yaml
shell> cat host
all:
  hosts:
    server:
      ip: 111.111.111.111

shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: server
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ip'] }}"
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

    "msg": "111.111.111.111"
```